# read::Int not working in Haskell in example

Tags: haskell

Here is the problem. It looks simple yet

```
main = do 
   s <- getContents
   let list = map (read::Int) (words s)
   print list

    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `String -> a0'
    Probable cause: `read' is applied to too few arguments
    In the first argument of `map', namely `(read :: Int)'
    In the expression: map (read :: Int) (words s)
```

The problem was that I thought :: is like casting and I have to put the return type. The solution was to add full wanted |function signature instread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` is a function (of type `Read a => String -> a`), so it can't have type `Int`. You could do `read :: String -> Int`, or you could put a type signature on `list` rather than `read`, so you get:

```
let list :: [Int]
    list = map read (words s)
```